# Angular Unittest jest throwError -> error gets not detected

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs

Say I got a component with the following method:

```
someMethod() {
  this.someService
    .doServicesMethod(this.id)
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => (this.loading = false)),
      catchError((e) => {
        this.showErrorMessage = true;
        return throwError(e);
      }),
    )
    .subscribe({
      next: (result) => {/* handle result*/},
    });
}
```

Now I want to write a unittest using jest, so I go like:

```
it(
  'should test someMethod',
  waitForAsync(() => {
    spyOn(someService, 'doServicesMethod').and.returnValue(throwError('someError'));

    expect(component.showErrorMessage).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.loading).toBeTruthy();

    try {
      component.someMethod();
    } catch (error) {
      expect(component.loading).toBeFalsy();
      expect(component.showErrorMessage).toBeTruthy();
    }
  }),
);
```

But the unittest doens't work. At first I tried without `waitForAsync` in which case the error isn't detected in this test, but somehow floats around after the test and gets detected during the next test which then fails with `someError`.

Using the `waitForAsync` the error gets detected but not in the try-catch-block, in which case the test itself fails.

Calling `tick();` after `component.someMethod();` detects the error, so the test jumps into the `catch`-block, but the error doesn't actually get caught -> the test fails anyway with `someError`.

I'm kinda out of ideas, so does anybody know how I get this test to work?

Answer (score 1):

I have always used the expect().toThrow() or expect().toThrowError()

```
it('should test someMethod', async () => {
    expect( () => {
        await component.someMethod()
    }).toThrow();
});
```

You can also catch specific errors by using `toThrowError(<Replace with Error>)`

If not using a promise, I have done:

```
it('should test someMethod', () => {
    expect( () => {
        component.someMethod()
    }).toThrow( ... );
});
```

If your try/catch was not working, and this syntax is not working, are you sure someMethod is actually throwing?

Sample function I have:

```
export function ExpandTextStringToArray(
    DataField: string,
    Separator: string = ',',
    TrimText: boolean = false
): string[] {
    if (DataField === undefined || DataField === null) {
        throw new Error(APPLICATION_EXCEPTIONS.VALUE_MUST_BE_STRING);
    }
    const ExpandedString: string[] = DataField.split(Separator);
    if (TrimText) {
        ExpandedString.forEach((Text, Index, Data) => {
            Data[Index] = Text.trim();
        });
    }
    return ExpandedString;
}
```

My test, which works and catches the throw:

```
it('should throw an exception when passing null for the DataField', () => {
    expect(() => {
        ExpandTextStringToArray(null);
    }).toThrowError(APPLICATION_EXCEPTIONS.VALUE_MUST_BE_STRING);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the approach did not work. `someMethod` doesn't return a promise, so there's nothing to `await` and the function itself doesn't throw (Received function did not throw).

Comment: Updated the answer for now Promise responses.  I have done this on functions in my libraries that manipulate data.